# How to design LDAP groups for access to applications?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm pretty new to LDAP and I have a question how I should design the LDAP groups (subgroups?) for centralised user management, for example with JIRA, Jenkins and other applications.

I have an open ldap setup on debian running with jira and jenkins authorising based on groups like for example this developers group:

```
cn=developers,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
dn: cn=developers,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
cn: developers
member: cn=John Doe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: groupOfNames
```

My question is on best practice for the LDAP setup in this kind of situation. Ideas and questions:

- Should I just continue to use the developer group and manage all
  authorization within individual applications like jira based on this
  group. So delete jira-developers in jira and work with developers
  group.
- Should I create individual groups for each application, e.g. (jira-developers-group) and just maintain each application individually in LDAP?
- Should I try to setup a subgroup (subordinate?) structure, so every member of developers is automatically a member of jira-developers, jenkins-developers etc?

I have the I've read http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ for a large part and thought it was helpful, but I'm still not sure what's the best / most common way to do it. The organisation is not very big, though I'd like to be future proof. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're using one group for each service. So one or more groups for users that should use jira and a different set of groups for jenkins and so forth. That way you have one central place to change group-membership and you do not have to add a user in every single system.

And as most systems just check for group-membership and not whether there is a common supergroup I'd just use simple groups.

To see which groups are for what system we're using the systems name in the groupname. So all jira related groups start with 'jira_', and all jenkins-related ones start with 'jenkins_'. And then there are 'jira_developers' and 'jira_qanda' and 'jira_admins' and 'jenkins_admins' and 'jenkins_project_a' and 'jenkins_project_b' and so forth.

But there might be different views to that.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. That's helpful.